Cannot open source file "SFML/Graphics"
I am trying to use SFML C++ and I want to use it with Visual Studio, I follow this tutorial on SFML website. But an error appeared:
E1696: cannot open source file "SFML/Graphics"

My code:
#include <SFML/Graphics>  

int main() {
   return 0; 
}  

I also tried adding ".hpp after "Graphics" but it didn't really work.
I researched a lot on the Internet but look like none solve my problems:

Fatal error: SFML/Graphics.hpp: no such file or directory exists (Stack Overflow)

fatal error: SFML\Graphics.hpp: No such file or directory #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp> (Reddit)

Cannot open include file: 'SFML/Graphics.hpp': No such file or directory... (SFML Forums)


None of them solved my problem.

Pretty sure it should be SFML/Graphics.hpp, so that's one of your multiple problems solved

Didn't work, too... Still the same error.

So the issues are, where is the file SFML/Graphics.hpp? And what have you done to tell your compiler where to find that file?

I didn't say it would work, I just said it's the first step. The basic issue is that you need to understand how to tell your compiler where to find header files. Until you understand that you cannot solve the problem. Compilers don't find header files by themselves, they need to be told.

So in Visual Studio you edit the project properties, and add entries to the 'Additional Include Directories' section. Have you done that? If you did, what did you put there?

Yes, I did, I followed the tutorial to put the directory into "Additional Include Directories" (D:\SFML-2.6.1\include).

OK, presumably your installation directory is D:\SFML-2.6.1? Check the spelling. Did you make sure you selected 'All Configurations', like the tutorial shows?

Yes I did it. Selected "All Configurations" and Platform "x64"

The compiler looks where you've told it, and so it should find the header file. Clearly you have made some mistake somewhere because this is not complicated but I've run out of ideas.

Obviously if you selected platform x64 then make sure you are doing a 64 bit build. It will just be some trivial mistake like that.

Please show a directory listing of the D:\SFML-2.6.1\include folder.

The "include" folder only have a folder inside it: SFML

Inside the SFML:

Audio
Graphics
Network
System
Window
Audio.hpp
Config.hpp
GpuPreference.hpp
Graphics.hpp
Main.hpp
Network.hpp
OpenGL.hpp
System.hpp


Also Window.hpp

Assuming that the path is correct, and the include directory option has been correctly specified, then the include statement should be: #include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>. If that still does not work then there must be something else wrong with your setup. You can check the output in the build logs, or the project properties in Visual Studio.

I even tried #include <D:/SFML-2.6.1/include/SFML/Graphics.hpp>
VS found the file, but there are still other files error (cannot find Window.hpp, BlendMode.hpp, CircleShape.hpp,...)

Are you still having this issue? Just had this problem while reading the Beginning Game Programming with C++ book.
The solution I found is to check which platform is selected on the editor itself, right next to the "Local Windows Debugger" button. Visual Studio was not recognizing the header because I downloaded the 32 bits version, and the compiler was searching for a 64 one, maybe it is the same for you?
